# Transformação de Query

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, tabela-banco-de-dados

Alguém sabe se é possivel tranformar uma consulta do SQL SERVER em uma nova tabela?
Deixar de ser consulta para poder ser mostrada com um comando "show table" feita a partir de uma query por exemplo ?

Comment: Pouco clara sua pergunta , ao menos para mim , mas creio que se refira as tabelas de metadados , https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/returning-column-metadata-specific-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer criar uma nova tabela com base nos dados de uma consulta, utilize a cláusula `INTO`:

```
SELECT campo1,
       campo2,
       campo3
  INTO nova_tabela
  FROM tabela
```

---

> [**`SELECT` – Cláusula `INTO`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> `SELECT…INTO` cria uma tabela no grupo de arquivos padrão e insere nela as linhas resultantes da consulta.